Coverity : cov_analyze outputs
I am trying to run coverity in c source files and I am successfully able to run below steps

cov_configure
cov_build
cov_analyze

After the 3rd step, I get some failures reported from coverity like deadcode, overrun etc and few xmls get created in the intermediate folder.
However the readibilty of the errors is poor making it difficult to fix.
Is there a way to analyze output from cov_analyze step or are there any steps further that need to be run?

After running cov-analyze, the usual next step is to run cov-commit-defects, which imports the findings into the Coverity Connect web application for review.  That requires a running instance of Coverity Connect to commit to.
For an overview of the analysis steps, including the commit step, see the documentation page Steps to generate an analysis.
For information on setting up Coverity Connect, see Coverity Connect administration.

Alternatively, after running cov-analyze, one can run cov-format-errors to generate a directory of static HTML pages containing all of the findings, which can then be viewed by pointing a browser at those files (or arranging to serve them over HTTP using your own web server).  However, be aware that the static HTML display is missing many features that Coverity Connect has, the most important of which is persistent triage: the ability to make notes about a finding, perhaps mark some as incorrect or needing further investigation, and have that information carry forward to the "same" finding when it appears in a later analysis.

Thank you for the answer. But is there a way to analyze cov-analyze results without commit-defects commands, probably through another coverity command like format-errors?

Yes, that is possible.  I've now added info about cov-format-errors.
